# Spring Boot Post repository doesn't save any new data

Tags: spring-boot, post, crud

I'm studying spring boot's controller.
All of the other CRUD operations work well, except the POST request.
I've created a post repository, service, and controller, and I execute mocked tests. Network status was `201 created` but it actually doesn't save created data to the `PersonRepository`.

This is my `PersonController` test:

```java
@Test
public void postPerson() throws Exception {
    PersonDto personDto = PersonDto.of("ju", "book", "gwa", "doctor", "01011111111", LocalDate.now());

    mockmvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/person")
               .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).content(toJsonString(personDto)))
               .andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isCreated());

    List<Person> findAll = personRepository.findAll();
    findAll.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

This is the test result:

> MockHttpServletRequest:
>         HTTP Method = POST
>         Request URI = /api/person
>          Parameters = {}
>             Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8"]
>                Body = {"name":"ju","hobby":"book","address":"gwa","job":"doctor","phoneNumber":"01011111111","birthday":"2020-02-04"}
>       Session Attrs = {}
>
> Handler:
>                Type = com.fastcampus.javaallinone.project3.demo.controller.PersonController
>              Method = public void com.fastcampus.javaallinone.project3.demo.controller.PersonController.postPerson(com.fastcampus.javaallinone.project3.demo.model.dto.PersonDto)
>
> Async:
>       Async started = false
>        Async result = null
>
> Resolved Exception:
>                Type = null
>
> ModelAndView:
>           View name = null
>                View = null
>               Model = null
>
> FlashMap:
>          Attributes = null
>
> MockHttpServletResponse:
>              Status = 201
>       Error message = null
>             Headers = []
>        Content type = null
>                Body = 
>       Forwarded URL = null    Redirected URL = null
>             Cookies = []
>
> Hibernate: select person0_.id as id1_0_, person0_.address as
>   address2_0_, person0_.day_of_birthday as day_of_b3_0_,
>   person0_.month_of_birthday as month_of4_0_, person0_.year_of_birthday
>   as year_of_5_0_, person0_.deleted as deleted6_0_, person0_.hobby as
>   hobby7_0_, person0_.job as job8_0_, person0_.name as name9_0_,
>   person0_.phone_number as phone_n10_0_ from person person0_ where (
>   person0_.deleted=0)
>
> Person(id=1, name=martin, hobby=null, address=null, job=null,
>   phoneNumber=null, birthday=Birthday(dayOfBirthday=31,
>   monthOfBirthday=1, yearOfBirthday=1997), deleted=false) Person(id=2,
>   name=mars, hobby=null, address=null, job=null, phoneNumber=null,
>   birthday=Birthday(dayOfBirthday=21, monthOfBirthday=4,
>   yearOfBirthday=1995), deleted=false) Person(id=3, name=Amy,
>   hobby=null, address=null, job=null, phoneNumber=null,
>   birthday=Birthday(dayOfBirthday=1, monthOfBirthday=4,
>   yearOfBirthday=1997), deleted=false) Person(id=4, name=james,
>   hobby=null, address=null, job=null, phoneNumber=null,
>   birthday=Birthday(dayOfBirthday=1, monthOfBirthday=8,
>   yearOfBirthday=1997), deleted=false) Person(id=5, name=martin,
>   hobby=null, address=null, job=null, phoneNumber=null,
>   birthday=Birthday(dayOfBirthday=23, monthOfBirthday=1,
>   yearOfBirthday=1889), deleted=false)

PersonController:

```java
@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void postPerson(@RequestBody PersonDto personDto){
    personService.postPerson(personDto);
}
```

PersonSevice:

```java
@Transactional
public void postPerson(PersonDto personDto) {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.set(personDto);
    personRepository.save(person);
}
```

data.sql file:

```
insert into person(`id`,`name`,`year_of_birthday`,`month_of_birthday`,`day_of_birthday`) values (1,'martin',1997,1,31);
insert into person(`id`,`name`,`year_of_birthday`,`month_of_birthday`,`day_of_birthday`) values(2,'mars',1995,4,21);
insert into person(`id`,`name`,`year_of_birthday`,`month_of_birthday`,`day_of_birthday`) values(3,'Amy',1997,4,1);
insert into person(`id`,`name`,`year_of_birthday`,`month_of_birthday`,`day_of_birthday`) values(4,'james',1997,8,1);
insert into person(`id`,`name`,`year_of_birthday`,`month_of_birthday`,`day_of_birthday`) values(5,'martin',1889,1,23);
```

Please let me know where I'm going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: I've had spotty results in mockMvc controller tests when attempting to use repositories/services directly. Do a find call via mockMvc and see if you get a better result.